# How to make Intellij show logs when running a test method

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Suppose I have the following code:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( DummyTest.class );
@Test
public void test() {
    log.info("dummy log");
}
```

When I run the test method `test()` in Intellij, I didn't get any log in the console output. However, if I run the test via `mvn test` from commandline, I will get the log. BTW, I use testng.

So, how can I make Intellij to show the log?

Comment: If you added a `sout` in the test method, can you see that? Otherwise are you sure you are using a "real" logger, and not the "noop" version?

Comment: that should just work. if you click on the class in the run panel after executing the test: are there error messages related to the logger? Maybe IntelliJ picks up a log config that logs into files only. Try adding a log4j.xml (or what ever you use) in src/test/resources which contains a console logger.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - no log output at all in console.
Taking @wemu's advice, I added the following file to the `src/test/resources/` directory of my project, which gave me the debug ouput from both the test code and the classes under test.
Note: I'm using log4j2. The file needed will vary according to your logging framework.

log4j.xml:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<configuration monitorInterval="30">
    <appenders>
        <Console name='Console' target='SYSTEM_OUT'>
            <PatternLayout pattern='%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p [%t] %c{1.}.%M %m%n' />
        </Console>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level='trace'>
            <appender-ref ref='Console' />
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and as of mid 2020 the following line solved my problem:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME).addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
```